# how to get rid of the part that is highlighted in email header

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

How to get rid of the part that is highlighted in this email header? By the way ,I'm using `PHPMailer`.

[image]

Comment: The email header has to include the email address.

Comment: where do you want to get rid , on the site, on the email ?

Comment: from email, @MaxMuster

Comment: I think this question is hilarious. Are we doing fishing training here???

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. This address may not be *displayed* (For example Apple Mail always hides it by default, but other clients may not), but it will always be present in the actual headers, and you have no control over what the client does with it.